# How do I fix a Memorex USB 8GB flash drive that shows 0 B available?

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive

Memorex USB 8GB drive that shows 0 B available.
I don't know if it's mechanically broken or something is wrong with it.

Even disk part shows it as (See Disk 2)

[image]

Any ideas?

EDIT: The bios shows it as 2231 PRAM...

Comment: Does this answer help? http://superuser.com/questions/88509/usb-drive-not-showing-full-size It worked for me with a similar problem.

Comment: It doesn't :-( bummer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *No Media* status is a very bad sign. It usually means that the USB flash controller chip has lost the connection(s) to the memory chip(s) - it's a hardware problem.

Unless the data is very valuable (insert 4-5 figure number here)  - then you can ask one of the specialist data recovery centers - you can only throw the stick away and get a new one.

Answer (score 7):

I've run into this myself. Here's how I solved it when I saw the USB drive as a 2XXX PRAM device in Device Manager and it was missing from My Computer/This PC:

1. In Device Manager, find the PRAM device. If it's missing, unplug the drive and plug it back into a USB 2.0 port. Once you find it in Device Manager, right-click, uninstall.
2. Confirm as necessary so the device is uninstalled.
3. Unplug the device, then plug it back into a different USB port. If you have a USB 3.0 port, use it now.

Result: the drive appears as a normal USB drive as it's supposed to. Format it at your earliest convenience.

I think this happens if you format the drive as an EFI bootable disk.

Answer (score 0):

The "No Media" would bother me. Is it showing up in the Device Manager? Disk Manger? How old is it?

Assuming there was nothing critical on the disk, I would try this:

```
select disk 2
list partition
select partition 1
delete partition
```

Then create and format it again.

Comment: there is no partition on the drive to select :-(

Comment: Then try selecting the disk in diskpart, and running "clean", and "recover". Then try to re-create the partition. Also run "detail", and see if is shows anything.

Comment: Of course, I am leaning to it simply being bad. Maybe it has a long warranty. A lot of them do. I checked, most Memorex have a two-year warranty.

Comment: At least if it is not under warranty, a new Kingston 8GB flash drive is only $13.