# I can't open my pen drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I can't open my pen drive. When I inserted it to my computer it would just appear a removable disk and then when I tried to open it tells that there is no disk on the dirve. Can this be fixed? what should I do to open it so that I can Use it again. Hope you can help me with this problem. thanks!

Comment: Is this a new pen drive, or one that used to work and now has stopped working?

Comment: its a brand new pendrive(moserbear)......i bought it today

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/311111/how-do-i-fix-a-memorex-usb-8gb-flash-drive-that-shows-0-b-available

Answer (score 0):

I guess your pen drive isn't formatted. Or it is entirely formatted as for example a TrueCrypt volume, so unless you mount it using TrueCrypt, it will appear unformatted.

But if you haven't used any volume-wide encrypting, and it's a brand new drive as you now clarified, try right-clicking it in Explorer and selecting "Format...", then choose "FAT32" (assuming you're under Windows).

Comment: truecrypt is also not working in this case