# USB stick formatting problem

Tags: formatting, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [USB drive not showing full size](https://superuser.com/questions/88509/usb-drive-not-showing-full-size)

Well I'm embarrassed to even put this up.  I wasn't really paying attention and formatted my 8GB USB stick to 3.21 GB in windows 7.  Is there any way I can format it back to 8GB or did I just burn away 4 Gigs?

Comment: @DMA57361♦ Could you migrate my answer too please?

Comment: @KCotreau We normally only merge questions if the source question has upvoted answers that would add something new to the target question. Your answer is quite similar to the top voted answer on the target, and you don't have any votes that'll be lost here, so I'm not sure what the value of a merge would be in this case?