# USB not correctly formatted

Tags: usb-flash-drive, formatting

I have formatted a usb flash drive withs size of 2,5 GB and now it shows me that it's size is 8 MB. How can I fix it to be 2,5 GB again?

Comment: Operation System?

Comment: Could you please add more information to your question? Like what have you tried to fix the problem, the Operating System, and what format you are trying to get your flash drive to.

Comment: plug it into an ubuntu system and format it.... problem will be solved

Comment: I formatted it a couple of times with the cmd(windows 8.1). Now I type listdisk it shows me that its capacity is 8MB and that it has only one partition. When I try to select and delete the partition it says that there is no partition selected. Windows can't format it the usual way("Windows was unable to complete the format"). I tried BootIce too but it doesnt work. What shoud I do? P.S Sorry for the bad english

Comment: Also, in the Manage option it shows me that the flash drive format is RAW.

Comment: check this.  http://superuser.com/questions/752874/16-gb-usb-flash-drive-capacity-down-to-938-mb

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article with 3rd party software that may help: [Restore USB Flash Disk Back to Full Capacity](http://www.trishtech.com/2011/06/restore-usb-flash-disk-back-to-full-capacity/)

The article suggests that after removing a malware or after formatting the USB the capacity will not change and it shows step - by - step instructions how to restore your USB back to full capacity by using  [Bootice](http://www.pendriveapps.com/bootice-partition-flash-drive-edit-boot-sector/) application.

There are also step by step instructions without the 3rd party software:[Best Way To Restore USB Drive Back to Full Capacity!](http://www.avilpage.com/2014/02/best-way-to-restore-usb-drive-back-to.html)

From the article:

1. Open Run ( Windows + R ).
2. Type Diskpart and press Enter ( diskpart ).
3. Type list disk ( list disk ).
4. Type select disk 1 ( select disk 1 ).
5. Type clean and enter ( clean ).
6. Now you USB will show 0Bytes. Don't panic. Just unplug USB and insert again.
7. The system will prompt for fromat and do format.

Hope this helps

Comment: Please add some details to your link only answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can use Diskpart (commandline) and Format (GUI):

1. diskpart
2. list disk
3. select disk X (X = correct disk No.)
4. clean
5. create partition primary
6. list partition (just to be sure)
7. exit (go back to GUI)
8. format the disk

Worked for me in W7/64.