# 8GB USB drive shows 8MB size, can't format

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, format, filesystem-corruption

TL;DR:

- The USB is 8GB, it doesn't have any physical lock.
- It is a goku doll and it was a gift for my friend, there isn't any brand. Chip Genius says that it is generic.
- It is saying that it has 8MB and I can't restore it to their previous size or at least something that is not 8MB.
- I can tell that this USB was able to store at least 4GB, as we used it to store a ISO without problems.
- Even if it may be fake it wouldn't have 8MB, and we don't care if it is only 4GB or 6GB. We just want to make it usable again.
- Data recovery is not a problem here, we have backup of everything inside.
- I can't enter to the data inside the USB even if I make a partition via **diskpart** as Windows ask me to format it, and if I try to format it, Windows says that it can't finish the format.
- I think that the USB is corrupted as I plugged it out when the Wii was stuck reading it without response. I'm not sure if it is truly bricked or it is still salvable.

---

I have a 8GB USB pendrive stuck to 8MB, the USB thinks that it is 8MB and I can't do very much.

What happened:

> We were using it to charge iso files of Wii games to play in a fam's
>   Wii. The Wii's homebrew app **USB Loader GX** wasn't reading the game
>   (and actually there were two inside), but it was able to read before
>   using it today. So I tried in the computer to check what was wrong, I
>   changed the USB Loader in the Wii with another USB Loader And that USB
>   Loader bricked the USB, when it tried to read the game, the wii just
>   got stuck forever, I reset the wii and when I tried to check again
>   what was wrong, but the USB was dead and I couldn't format it that version of USB Loader messed up the USB when I resetted or the USB was almost dying from before.

I tried almost everything to save the USB, first, this USB doesn't have any type of physical lock, it is just the head of a Goku's doll.
I first supposed that the partition table was messed up (It somehow happened with a pendrive that I tried to use to format my PC and it just died by itself, something about partitions)
Now a friend told me that it may be the firmware so, here is all what I tried to do

++ Windows 10 Solutions

**Diskpart** //
It was able to clean the disk.
Size: 8 MB
Free: 8128 KB

**Using Format** //
In capacity it shows Unknown Capacity
File system: FAT (Default)
Allocation unit size: Default
Quick format ON.

I get the error Windows was unable to complete the format

**Error checking tool** //
I just can't use it because it asks to format the USB and I can't.

**CHKDSK /f /r** //
It shows this error

```
The type of the file system is RAW.
CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.
```

**Fake Flash Test v1.1.2** //
I couldn't even test it.

```
FAKEFLASHTEST v1.1.2  [SSi]
DRIVE 2 -    7.0MiB Generic Flash Disk 2.0         
FFT - Quick Size Test (destructive)
F:                       DRIVE 2 -    7.0MiB Generic Flash Disk 2.0         

Writing marker blocks to drive 2
100% complete  - 0 min 1 sec remaining
Reading back marker blocks...
159% complete - 0 min 1 sec remaining
Memory tested in blocks of 25600 sectors.

BAD MEMORY from sector 16064 (7.0MiB) to sector 16064 (7.0Mib)
Test took 0 seconds.

                         *** FAILED ***

DEVICE HAS DUPLICATE OR BAD BLOCKS!

Recommended maximum usable partition size: -4.0Mib (approx. Last good Sector=16064)

Unplug and re-connect the drive, then reformat it using Windows or RMPrepUSB.
```

**Chip Genius info** //
It shows me that it is a 32GB but is actually 8GB, not 32. Also that chip vendor and controller I couldn't find it online (Chinesse webpages showed up)

```
Description: [F:]USB Mass Storage Device(Generic Flash Disk 2.0)
Device Type:  Mass Storage Device

Protocal Version: USB 2.00
Current Speed: High Speed
Max Current: 100mA

USB Device ID: VID = 214B PID = 2060

Device Vendor: Generic
Device Name: USB2.0 FlashDisk
Device Revision: 1001

Manufacturer: Generic
Product Model: Flash Disk 2.0
Product Revision: 6.80

Controller Vendor: HuaYi
Controller Part-Number: HY6919
Flash ID code:      453C98B3 - SanDisk - 1CE/Single Channel [TLC] -> Total Capacity = 32GB

Hint: : Please exit this program and RE-PLUG your USB Flash Drive before you can operate it!

Tools on web: http://dl.mydigit.net/search/?type=all&q=HY6919


Possible Flash Part-Number
----------------------------
Unknown


Flash ID mapping table
----------------------------
[Channel 0] [Channel 1]
453C98B37672    --------
--------    --------
--------    --------
--------    --------
```

**Flash Drive/Card Tester** //

Read & Write does the same thing:

```
00:53:25.25 - -------------------------------- New test process started --------------------------------
00:53:25.26 - Started "Reading test data" for drive F: 7MB, "Generic, Flash Disk 2.0, 6.80, ", 512b
00:53:25.53 - Completed "Reading test data" for drive F: 7MB, "Generic, Flash Disk 2.0, 6.80, ", 512b
00:53:25.53 - Tested total 7.999MB in 0:00:00 with 31.768MB/s
00:53:25.53 - Total read errors: Fatal=0, Recoverable=0
```

Read Write and Compare starts to show errors, This is a fragment of the test as it is pretty long:

```
00:57:15.25 - ! Error in data at LBN = 240 (Off: 0h): expected 000401C0h, encountered 01FF01C0h.
00:57:15.25 - ! Error in data at LBN = 241 (Off: 0h): expected 000401C4h, encountered 01FF01C4h.
00:57:15.25 - ! Error in data at LBN = 242 (Off: 0h): expected 000401C8h, encountered 01FF01C8h.
00:57:15.25 - ! Error in data at LBN = 243 (Off: 0h): expected 000401CCh, encountered 01FF01CCh.
00:57:15.26 - ! Error in data at LBN = 244 (Off: 0h): expected 000401D0h, encountered 01FF01D0h.
00:57:15.26 - ! Error in data at LBN = 245 (Off: 0h): expected 000401D4h, encountered 01FF01D4h.
00:57:15.26 - ! Error in data at LBN = 246 (Off: 0h): expected 000401D8h, encountered 01FF01D8h.
00:57:15.26 - ! Error in data at LBN = 247 (Off: 0h): expected 000401DCh, encountered 01FF01DCh.
00:57:15.28 - ! Error in data at LBN = 248 (Off: 0h): expected 000401E0h, encountered 01FF01E0h.
00:57:15.28 - ! Error in data at LBN = 249 (Off: 0h): expected 000401E4h, encountered 01FF01E4h.
```

**BOOTICE** // This couldn't even do anything, I can't use any option of Process PBR, Process MBR is disabled. I tried to format the "8MB" drive with it using FAT32 and without optimized internal structure. It was successful but Windows doesn't detect it and ask me to format it... Also process MBR is now available but it doesn't do anything.

**H2testw** // Can't use it, it asks me to format the drive. (Error accesing target)

**HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool V2.2.3** // It says Failed to format the device

**RMPrepUSB V2.1.744** // For some reason it says *UNMOUNTED*, I tried all the tests and it always says

```
Cannot find drive 2
Please ensure you have specified DRIVE=n where n is a NUMBER not a letter!
```

and it crashes afterwards.

**Check Flash V1.16.1** // It says:  when I choose the USB.
Any write and read test with default options with **Use Temporary File**:

```
File or device error: The volume does not contain a recognized file system.
Please make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted
```

As Logical Drive

```
Test fail: Invalid handle.
```

As Physical Drive

```
File or device error: Access is denied
```

**TestDisk v7.2** // I choose the problematic USB and "none", after that I choosed FAT32, after that nothing happened so I switched to NTFS, I pressed dump and it shows me an interesting message of missing operating system. Next I went back and picked "Analyse" and it shows me different partitions of what I think that it was what I did these last hours. (I tried it before but it didn't show anything to me) Check the gallery please.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TujgN.jpg

**Linux Things** // On linux I instaled in another USB Slax so I can use the terminal and try to fix it through Linux.

- I used the command dd of=/dev/zero if=/dev/sdc bs=1M but nothing happened
- I tried to use Gparted but it didn't work, it couldn't even make a partition table nor format it to make these 8MB accessible.
- I tried to use fdisk and delete partitions but when I first tried it, there wasn't one
- I tried Linux version of Test Disk but nothing happened too, also, when I first tried there wasn't any partition too.

I did almost everything that I could think and get in for, I just can't format it, I can't fix it, I can't update the firmware nor search it, I can't even wipe the info inside to start anew, I can't make it detect that it has truly 8GB and not that misery of 8MB and nothing. The most miraculous thing was when I tried to change the cylinders or heads on Testdisk and it changed from 8MB to 128~something, but I was in linux and I couldn't check if I can enter the USB as I'm not a Linux users. Also I think that I would mess it a lot more than it is, so I didn't touch it.
Can someone help me with this or has an idea of what can I do? Thanks. I may be still trying something so some of the results from Test Disk will be different if I show them again.

- Also I can truly tell that it may not be a fake drive, it truly is a 8GB drive and I was using it a couple of weeks ago for storing 7GB at least.

Comment: The DD command you tried in Linux reads the entire drive and discards the data, i.e., it does nothing. Basically it takes your drive as an Input File (if) and writes it to the Output File (of) /dev/zero, which is a virtual device which only outputs zeros and cannot be written to. Did you run gparted as root? Try using gparted (sudo gparted) to write a new partition table to the drive. Should be under the "Device" menu, pick the option that mentions creating a partition table. You probably want dos, not gpt, but either should work.

Comment: PC Luddite - Thanks you for changes! I didn't check any rules here before asking for help.

Comment: @LayneBernardo The slax linux that I used doesn't have sudo installed, it has got bash instead (Also, I was booting slax from an USB) I installed sudo but I wasn't sure if I was with root permissions or not. I don't know how to check if I have them too. I'm going to try it again.

Comment: bash and sudo have no relation whatsoever. You can use `su` if `sudo` isn't available. Anyway this can be solved in Windows easily with diskpart. See [8GB memory stick only showing 49MB](https://superuser.com/q/878108/241386)

Comment: @LayneBernardo Ok I finished testing gparted again with su command, Gparted drops the error "Unrecognised disk label", also it shows 8MB and not 8GB like the USB truly is.

Comment: @phuclv Diskpart works but I can't format the usb  [it shows this error](https://i.imgur.com/kmWWt5r.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)

Comment: maybe you get a fake usb ? is it a genuine brand ?

Comment: @Tetsujin It doesn't, I tried it and on details volume and details disk it says 8MB, it isn't locked physically

Comment: @Raymond the usb was a gift for my friend, we didn't buy it, I ain't think that they're from a genuine brand too (It may be chinesse due to Chip Genius), it is a goku's doll and the USB is inside the head.
But I can tell that it has at least 5GB. If the size weren't genuine, it wouldn't be able to store a 4GB ISO without reading problems
Even if it is a counterfake, it wouldn't have 8 MB

Comment: The drive may be fried. It sounds like the partition table is just corrupted, but there's no reason gparted shouldn't be able to write a new partition table to the disk (with root permissions). I know Windows Disk Management will sometimes fail on drives for no obvious reason, but I've never had an issue nuking a drive (wiping and rewriting the partition table) using gparted except when the drive itself is faulty.

Comment: Read https://www.balena.io/blog/did-etcher-break-my-usb-sd-card/

Comment: It's a firmware issue, you can only address it using tools that work with firmware (MPtools). In general these are poorly documented and translated, and time/effort put into reviving such a USB flash drive outweighs just getting an new one for a few $.

Answer (score 1):

I deal with these a lot as it is my job to recover data from such devices. These symptoms are caused by either firmware issues or the inability for the controller to 'talk' to the physical NAND.

First test, check physical capacity in Disk Management or the equivalent in your OS:

[image]

Only if correct physical capacity is shown you'll be able to tackle this with DiskPart or similar: As long as the controller does not see or communicate with the NAND correctly all the usual guides as found on the internet (DiskPart, chkdsk, etc.) are a waste of time and effort.

If some small amount of MB is listed then controller is alive and you can then attempt test 2.

Test 2, get FLashGenius or a similar tool and see if at least detects the NAND:

[image]

It does not: Then either NAND chip is dead or there's a physical issue causing the controller not to see the NAND. A physical issue may be resolved by re-balling the NAND chip, or redo solder joints in case of TSOP NAND package.

If the NAND chip is correctly detected then most likely the firmware is corrupt (like flash translation layer). In this case you may be able to revive the USB Flash drive using a so called 'MPtool' utility.

MPtools are mostly poorly documented and translated Chinese tools. Consider that even if you get the drive going, that the root cause for the issue is most likely ultra low quality NAND, and that the next problem is just around the corner. This is not matter of opinion but matter of experience. Do not trust such a 'repaired' device with data that is actually of value.

If you need to recover the data from a USB flash drive exhibiting these symptoms, the NAND chip needs to be removed and dumped using a NAND reader. The dump then requires further processing to be transformed into a logical file system from which data can be recovered.

[image]

Bottom line: If you need to recover the data from such a scenario then it's practically undoable using DIY methods. NAND readers are relatively cheap, the software to work with the NAND dumps is not.

If data is of no concern then the effort of reviving the USB flash drive IMO isn't worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I was almost in the same situation and tried almost everything you did, but had zero success.

I think the problem with my usb-drive was in its controller: for some reason it reported wrong drive size. So, the last resort option may be firmware overwriting.

I tried this and it helped me to rescue my drive, but be very careful with these steps, because you can just turn your usb-drive into brick.

1. Get your device vendorId and productId (VID and PID). Mine was 0951 and 1646. The simplest way for me was Linux `lsusb` command.
2. Find a program which can rewrite firmware for your usb-drive. As I understand, it depends on it's controller model and version. Mine was Phison PS2251-50. I've detected it via search [here](https://flashboot.ru/iflash/). The detected program was MPALL v3.12.0A  (for Windows).
3. Download the program suitable for your device. Double-check that downloaded version supports your controller. The first version of MPALL I've downloaded contained an utility to read info about usb-drive. After I've dug into this info, I understood that I need another version of MPALL.
4. Try to fill all necessary fields. MPALL has dreadful UX, better use an instruction for filling all the fields. I've used [this one](https://www.usbdev.ru/articles/a_phison/mpall-repair/) (it's in Russian, sorry, I found no English resources for that). I don't think other programs for this task have better UX.
5. Upload a new firmware to your device.

I did it for the first time in my life, but my usb-drive works now. Hope this helps somebody. See also [this article](https://habr.com/ru/post/98339/) in Russian.