# USB Drive missing space, no unallocated space found in Device Manager

Tags: usb, partitioning, formatting

I followed the link below to try and fix this issue but unfortuantly DiskPart, GParted or any other method has been unsuccessful. It's a 32GB flash drive and I'm seeing 1.8GB. Any ways of totally wiping and reformatting this to a stock flash drive?

[16 GB USB flash drive capacity down to 938 MB](https://superuser.com/questions/752874/16-gb-usb-flash-drive-capacity-down-to-938-mb)

Comment: Is this a relatively new drive? What caused this? Have you ever successfully stored and retrieved 32GB data using the drive? I'm asking because it could very well be a fake that has reverted back to its original 2GB size.

Comment: It is a 32GB. I used it last week to install a bootable image. Something got messed up though & that's what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: What file system are you using? FAT16 max is 1.8-2gb and that is ALL it can handle.  Did you try FAT32 or NTFS?

Comment: Also related: [16 GB USB flash drive capacity down to 938 MB](//superuser.com/q/752874/354511), [Flash disk capacity turns from 32 GB to 4 MB](//superuser.com/q/937410/354511), [USB drive not showing full size](//superuser.com/q/88509/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive shows as 16 MB and is unusable](//superuser.com/q/50207/354511), [1 GB space left after formatting a 16 GB flash drive?](/q/339489/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive turned to 1 GB after writing an ISO image onto it](/q/759602/354511) and [Toshiba pen drive shows 4 MB instead of 8 GB; what could have happened to it?](/q/927680/354511)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem several times. When Gparted, Diskpart, Disk Manager fails me (often times before) I use [BootIce](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bootice.html). I'm sure there are other alternatives but this is one of my many recommendations and I've found to be more convenient and portable than EaseUs, etc... mention in the link.

It's never been my "go to" program but it does offer more functions, control and user friendly interface than DiskPart and Disk Management. ie: more say over partitioning, specifically the "hidden" partition mentioned in the link, drive letters, etc... check it out, if it doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: I'm not to sure how to use this tool. I tried going through and re-formating and setting the partition table but its still showing a total of 1.9GB. Is there a tut. on this or anything?