# USB used as bootable but when I deleted from disk management the unallocated left is 8gb out of 32GB

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I used GPT bootable disk but didn't boot when I tried installing. So wanted to format the disk back to normal but can not format. So I went to disk management and delete all files in usb but the unallocated become 8gb from 32GB. I tried already dispart and clean but still left with 8gb. I have checked attributes but none is read only. Just wondering were the other storage space went. I have tried also the free partition tool but nothing happened and still unable to format after assigning drive letter.

Comment: my situation is very similar to this 2014 thread https://superuser.com/questions/752874/16-gb-usb-flash-drive-capacity-down-to-938-mb but the thread has still no answers. The flash drive is still new and 32GB reason wanted to recover the storage that is lost.

Comment: This usually means a dying/dead disk. If a disk manager can't fix it or reformatting can't, the drive is dead.

Comment: this is a new 32gb and used for mp3 and mp4 with no issues until yesterday I format to use as bootable disk GPT but it didn't work so I decided to delete data from disk mgt and now left with the unlocated 8gb. I think it has to do with the iso img which I can't locate and delete to open up the storage. Done diskpart and clean but to no avail.

Comment: when you say "Done diskpart" ... what does that mean? and "went to disk management and delete all files" ... one does not delete **files** in disk management

Comment: If the disk manufacturer has a firmware update tool, you might try it in the hope of fixing a bad firmware. Otherwise, the disk might be dead.

Comment: It is possible this is a fake usb stick that really is 8gb, but was altered to create a 32gb partition with rollover. If you would write more than 8gb to it, files would become corrupt.

Comment: While new drives bought from reputable merchants SHOULD last for a time, there's no guarantee it WILL work for a long time. USB sticks are temporary tools, and they are subject to more physical wear than other storage media, plus there can just be errors in manufacturing that are not caught. The repair options are very limited, and all this is assuming the drive is legit and not a fake.