# Toshiba pendrive shows 4 MB instead of 8 GB; what could have happened to it?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have a Toshiba 8 GB pendrive. All of a sudden, it's showing total space 4 ***MB***. I have tried `diskpart` and various other software, but no gain.
The disk management is also not showing unallocated space. Can someone suggest what happened to the pendrive?

Comment: Also related: [16 GB USB flash drive capacity down to 938 MB](https://superuser.com/q/752874/354511), [Flash disk capacity turns from 32 GB to 4 MB](https://superuser.com/q/937410/354511), [USB drive not showing full size](https://superuser.com/q/88509/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive shows as 16 MB and is unusable](https://superuser.com/q/50207/354511), [1 GB space left after formatting a 16 GB flash drive?](https://superuser.com/q/339489/354511),  and [16 GB USB flash drive turned to 1 GB after writing an ISO image onto it](https://superuser.com/q/759602/354511).

Answer (score 3):

The internal flash mapping table got corrupted. Due to the use of extremely cheap component, it sadly sometime happens to pendrive.

If the manufacturer (or someone else, as the controller manufacturer) publicly released the tool yo reset the flash table, you can try to use it to recover all your space. Anyway, I will **not** trust that pen drive anymore.