# toshiba 16gb drive turns to 4mb

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

My toshiba pen drive is now 4mb and i'm really freaking out. I have tried everything from easeus partition master, testdisk, hp usb disk utility. I've searched the entire web for help and nothing has worked. I even tried diskpart. When i go to the disk manager, there are no unallocated spaces. It's just the 4mb. I **REALLY REALLY** need help!!!

Comment: Sounds like a hard failure.  If that is the case there isn't very much that can be done, you have tried, nearly everything we could suggest or a variation of it.  Hopefully you have backups.

Comment: @RogUE - I don't see how that could possibly be a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @Ramhound Why can't it be a 'fake' drive as mentioned in the dup?

Comment: @Ramhound: Question is so annoyingly lacking in detail, that it may be a duplicate as marked by RogUE. No mention if drive was used before as 16 GB, no mention what he did with all that software listed and what not worked...

Comment: Also related: [How do I fix my USB drive to get its original 8 GB size back?](//superuser.com/q/382242/354511), [USB drive not showing full size](https://superuser.com/q/88509/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive shows as 16 MB and is unusable](https://superuser.com/q/50207/354511), [1 GB space left after formatting a 16 GB flash drive?](https://superuser.com/q/339489/354511), [16  GB USB flash drive turned to 1  GB after writing an ISO image onto it](https://superuser.com/q/759602/354511), and [Toshiba pen drive shows 4  MB instead of 8  GB; what could have happened to it?](/q/927680/354511)

Answer (score 0):

It may be one of two things.

1. It may simply be defective, though assuming you have used it without issue in the past this may not be the case.
2. It has a corrupted filesystem, which would unfortunately require a format and erase any data.

If you suspect it is neither of these, it may need to be replaced unfortunately. It seems that you have already run many of the tests that I would have run.